# Terminal urxvt shows squares instead of ASCII bold characters

Tags: terminal, gentoo, fonts, openbox, rxvt

I have just installed urxvt terminal, but the characters with bold formatting are replaced by squares:

[image]

When I copy the squares and paste them elsewhere, the text is displayed fine.
What configuration do I have to change to show bold characters? Thanks.

(I'm using Gentoo and Openbox.)

Comment: Try to use a lesser archaic terminal software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've installed xterm and now urxvt displays bold text properly.

Comment: You can accept also your own answer. Self-answered questions are very well liked here.